# Hyperlinked column to open as a popup with parameter via POST in a Highcharts pie drilldown data array?

Tags: javascript, php, post, highcharts

I have create a pie drilldown chart. I want to pop up a detailed information table when the user clicks on the drilldown data array button. How would I modify the demo chart [pie with Drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-drilldown/) so that a hyperlinked column in the drilldown series opens as a popup to an test.php with appropriate parameters?

I am trying the following:

```
.......
series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',

            data: [{
                name:'v7.0',
                y:0.5,
                url:'info.php?parent:v7.0&child:0.5'
                },
                {
                name:'v8.0',
                y:0.5,
                url:'info.php'  // How to using POST and send these parameter (parent:v8.0&child:0.5)  ????
                }]
        },
```

I understand that what I am trying to do is not correct. Can anybody help regarding this?

Comment: So after a click on a slice, chart should be drilled and a table shoud be printed?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console log? From your sample code, it looks like your URL parameters may not be formatted correctly. For example, instead of `['v9.0', 8.11,url:'info.php'?parent:v9.0&child:8.11],`, try `['v9.0', 8.11,url:'info.php?parent:v9.0&child:8.11'],` (move the single quote to the end of your URL string). Does this help at all?

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan, YES, after click on a slice then click the rest drilldown data will be popup a window that contain the drill data info

Comment: @ Mike Zavarello, got syntax error

Comment: Att the beginning your array for each point is incorrect. You should use object instaed of array with field names. This is wrong in syntax. Right format: {name:'v7.0', y:0.5,url:'info.php'?parent:v7.0&child:0.5}. Secondly, you can catch the [drilldown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) event and call your custom action.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan, i have update my question as you said ,but still got syntax error

Comment: You replaced that wrong. Please use object not object in array.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan, i have update my question ,but still got syntax error,am i missing anything ?

Comment: Use the jslint.com to verify the JSON. You cannot place url:'info.php'?parent:v7.0&child:25.13, because you have extra quote. Whole url should be quated.